# How to not insert duplicate images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what I have done is that, I have created a function that retrives data(images) from the database using XMLHttpRequest and appends it to `td` every 5000 milliseconds. Now as they are appended every 5000 milliseconds, if the data retrieved is not changed then it keeps appending the same data again and again. To stop it I attached custom attributes to the images with their IDs but I am not sure how would I stop it from appending duplicated items. This is my JS:

```
function getAlbumImages() {
    var xhr2 = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr2.open('GET', 'admin/images_data.php');

    xhr2.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
        if(xhr2.readyState == 4 && xhr2.status == 200) {
            var album_photos = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
            for(var i = 0; i < album_photos.length; i++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                var imagewrap = document.createElement('div');
                imagewrap.className = "image-wrap";
                    var imagemenu = document.createElement('div');
                    imagemenu.className = "image-menu";
                        var imagemenuimg1 = document.createElement('img');
                        imagemenuimg1.src = "img/edit_img.png";
                        var imagemenuimg2 = document.createElement('img');
                        imagemenuimg2.src = "img/close.png";
                    var imagewrapimg = document.createElement('img');
                    imagewrapimg.className = "thumbnail";
                    imagewrapimg.src = "admin/album_photos/" + album_photos[i].Image_Path;
                    imagewrapimg.setAttribute("data-image-id", album_photos[i].Image_ID);
                document.getElementById("tiare").appendChild(td);
                td.appendChild(imagewrap);
                imagewrap.appendChild(imagemenu);
                imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg1);
                imagemenu.appendChild(imagemenuimg2);
                imagewrap.appendChild(imagewrapimg);
            }
        }
    }
    xhr2.send(null);
}

setInterval(function(){
    getAlbumImages();
}, 5000);
```

And the markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- <div class="big_image" id="drop_zone">
            <img src="" id="big_img" />
        </div -->
        <div class="images_holder">
            <div class="header">
                Album Name - Photo Album
                <span class="close"><img src="img/close.png" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <table width="80%">
                    <tr id="tiare">

                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="drop_zone">
            Drag/Drop images to upload.
        </div>
        <div style="height: 30px; width: 80%; color: white; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
            <p id="progress_bar" style="width: 0%; background-color: red;"></p>
        </div>
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what happens the first time:
[image]

And this is what happens afterwards:
[image]

*See the duplicated images*

How can I stop it from appending the duplicated? Thanks in advance. :)

P.S: NO JQUERY ALLOWED. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if instance with same ID or URL is at page before insert

```
        if(document.querySector('div.thumbnail[data-image-id="' + album_photos[i].Image_ID + '"]')){
            continue;
        }
```

Or save list of all inserted id's in memory ( as array or object { id: url } ) and check if this item already loaded